# How to Open Browser's Same Tab after click on JavaFX app every time?

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a JavaFx App, which is used to show Notification 
on Desktop and When I click on notification-tray(a javaFX window) It open the browser
with given URL using code-

```
ChatServer c=new ChatServer();    
HostServicesDelegate hostServices =HostServicesFactory.getInstance(c);
hostServices.showDocument(s);
```

where ChatServer is main-class of my JavaFX app.

But the problem is that when I click on notification-tray again,
it open new tabs in Browser and I just want that it refresh same
tab in browser if I click on it next time.
Is there any way to refresh same tab of browser using JavaFX?
If anyone know please let me know.

Thanks in Advance!